# Handling error flow in single activity MVVM architecture: observers isn't triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm using MVVM in single activity application. As possible solution for error flow I decided to use activity as aggregation point for error representation(I considered that activity in this case is the most suitable place for this because it is basic View for any other Views in single activity scenario). I'm using SingleLiveEvent for passing errors(SingleLiveEvent implementation taken from [here](https://github.com/wasabeef/kotlin-mvvm/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/jp/wasabeef/util/SingleLiveEvent.kt)).

But in my case I don't receive any error updates from my ViewModels.
As example of my flow:

**MessageDialogViewModel.kt**

```
class MessageDialogViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application), MessageApi {
    val TAG: String = "DialogViewModel: "

    val message: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val errorLiveEvent: SingleLiveEvent<BaseCommand> = SingleLiveEvent()


    override fun sendMessage() {
        Log.i(TAG, " sendMessage: start")
        if (message.value.isNullOrBlank()) {
            Log.i(TAG, " sendMessage: blank")
            errorLiveEvent.value = BaseCommand.Error(null, "Message cannot be empty")
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, " sendMessage: ${message.value}")
            Repository.getInstance(getApplication()).sendMessage(message.value!!)
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
     private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by lazy {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
        }

        private val mainTaskViewModel: MainTaskViewModel by lazy {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainTaskViewModel::class.java)
        }

        private val messageDialogViewModel: MessageDialogViewModel by lazy {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MessageDialogViewModel::class.java)
        }
//////
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        //fixme merge observers
        loginViewModel.singleLiveEvent.observe(this,
            Observer {
                when (it) {
                    is BaseCommand.Success -> {
                        navigate()
                    }
                    is BaseCommand.Error -> showDialog(
                        errorTitle = it.error?.title,
                        errorMessage = it.error?.desc
                    )


                }
            })
        mainTaskViewModel.errorLiveEvent.observe(this,
            Observer {
                when (it) {
                    is BaseCommand.Success -> {

                    }
                    is BaseCommand.Error -> {
                        showToast(it.error)
                        if (it.error?.code == 500) {
                            navController.navigate(R.id.action_mainTaskFragment_to_loginFragment)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        )

        messageDialogViewModel.errorLiveEvent.observe(this,
            Observer {

                Log.i(TAG,"messageDialogViewModel.errorLiveEvent")
                when (it) {
                    is BaseCommand.Success -> {

                    }
                    is BaseCommand.Error -> {
                        showToast(null, it.errorMessage)
                    }
                }
            })

    }
```

And in I don't receive anything in my **MainActivity**.
Any help or suggestion about better architecture solution appreciated.

Comment: I think in mvvm concept, it only support one to one binding ViewModel to UI, but inside of repository you can access many resource from other datasource or DAO. Thats why you need to inject what you need to repository

Comment: @NandaZ Thanks for your comment, it gave me idea to implement MainActivityViewModel to pass error messages, but I still don't know why I cannot receive data on my observers in this case.

Comment: it because you never call this method `sendMessage()`

Comment: @NandaZ this method binded to MessageDialogFragment layout

Comment: do your log  console can print this line  `sendMessage: start` ?

Comment: @NandaZ, yes, I'm getting both messages, `sendMessage: start` and `sendMessage: blank`

Comment: Can you change `SingleLiveEvent` to `MutableLiveData` and see if it works? Also, irrelevant to the problem but, calling observe in `onResume` is a bad idea. If you go to some other activity or other app and comes back to the activity, it will create duplicate observers.

Comment: @SanlokLee thanks for advice adout `onResume`. Tried to change to `MutableLiveData` - no result

Comment: Honestly none of what LiveData offers was sufficient for my purposes in this regard, that's why I wrote https://github.com/Zhuinden/event-emitter which could potentially fix your problem. Though you have so many `it`s in your code that I lose track.

Answer (score 0):

Use `errorLiveEvent.setValue(BaseCommand.Error(null, "Message cannot be empty"))` instead of `errorLiveEvent.value = BaseCommand.Error(null, "Message cannot be empty")`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to switch on postValue. No difference.

Comment: I checkout ```SingleLiveEvent``` and i think you need to call ```errorLiveEvent.setValue(BaseCommand.Error(null, "Message cannot be empty"))``` insted of ```errorLiveEvent.value = BaseCommand.Error(null, "Message cannot be empty")```

Comment: changed answer.